# webview using progressbar in android

Tags: android, webview

```
*

> MainActivity.java

*
package com.example.net_progress;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import com.example.net_progress.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public MainActivity() {
        //pb.setProgress(progress);

    }
    WebView wv;
    ProgressBar pb;
    Button go;
    String url;
    EditText et;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        go=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        go.setOnClickListener(this);
        wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wv.setWebChromeClient(Myclient());


        pb.setMax(100);
    }
private WebChromeClient Myclient() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
public void setValue(int progress) {
        pb.setProgress(progress);       
    }
    boolean validateUrl(String url)
    {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button1)
        {
            url=et.getText().toString();
            if(validateUrl(url))
            {
            wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv.loadUrl("http://"+url);
            pb.setProgress(0);
            }

        }

    }


}

package com.example.net_progress;

import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class Myclient extends WebChromeClient {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView wv, int newProgress) {            
        MainActivity mn=new MainActivity();
        mn.setValue(newProgress);

        super.onProgressChanged(wv, newProgress);
    }

}
```

I've added codes of `MainActivity.java` and `webclient.java`. The website loading into `WebView`, But the progress of the WebView doesn't show into `ProgressBar`. please help me!

Its enough for me.
If you have the knowledge of webservices in android give some idea about that. sure that will help me mutch. thanking you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in onCreate()

`this.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);`

this will make progress visible

Answer (score 0):

`this.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);`

this will make progress visible on the actionbar